# Using "had better" in information questions

Tags: grammar

For some reason, I can't find an information question with *had better* in any websites, no grammar rules covering this! It's all about yes/no questions. It got me thinking if there is something about using had better with a question word. For example does this question sound natural to a native speaker?

> What had you better do if you've lost your child in a mall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Had better" is used to strongly suggest a particular course of action.  While it can be included in questions, the only typical use would be suggestions phrased as questions:

> **Hadn't you better** get to school?  It's already almost time for your class.

The speaker is not really asking a question here.  It's simply phrased as a question because this can sound *more polite*.  This is why the responses to these questions are normally either:

> Yes, I had (because ...)
>
> No, I don't have to (because ...)

In this it's not really different from other questions that ask for confirmation:

> Weren't you late to class yesterday?
>
> Didn't you wash your face after you woke up?

However, in some contexts "had better" works the same as "should" or "ought".  So it is *possible* to use "had better" in an information question, as in your example:

> What is something you **had better** do if you've lost your child in the mall?

but, at least to me, this still sounds slightly odd.  For clarity I would instead say:

> What is something you **should** do if you've lost your child in the mall?

or even better:

> **What should you do** if you've lost your child in the mall?

Comment: Interesting. So there _is_ something about using had better in information questions. I see even if you rephrased the question, you still have a preference for _should_ . I assume other native speakers of English must feel the same. Am I right?

Comment: I agree, "had better" sounds old fashioned. "Should" is used much more commonly.

Comment: @Yuri yes I think of it as somewhat formal, but not really *archaic*.  It's a phrasing I would associate with a stuffy British upper-class period drama like *Downton Abbey*, or even both together,  "You should had better".  In any case, because it's a phrase most commonly used with a kind of *admonition*, I wouldn't use it in your example sentence because it would sound rude and insensitive, as if I was telling you that you had done something wrong.